# How to import an Android Projects with git into workspace using egit?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit

In my projects I use some Android Libraries that are hosted on github, for example, [facebook android sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). Until now I downloaded the .zip with the library and added it to my workspace. This made keeping up to date libraries were a tedious job.

I want to use the option "Import > Git" in eclipse to import the Android Projects. And later use "Team > Pull" to obtain the latest versions of these projects. Is that possible? How?

My two principal problems are:

- The android project there is not in the root of the repository, and
- there is not .project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Mylyn and the [Mylyn Github connector](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/GitHub/UserGuide) into Eclipse using the update manager or the marketplace client. Afterwards you can use *Import -> Git -> From Github* and only need to give it the repository name of the github project. That will clone the repository, so you have the files locally on your system (but not yet known as normal projects in the Eclipse workspace).

Independent of using the connector or any other method to clone the github repository, afterwards you need to [import the cloned code into the workspace](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Importing_projects), so that Eclipse knows about it and can manage it as normal Java/Android/whatever projects. This can best be done by opening the git perspective, expanding the repository node and using the context menu "Import projects" on the "working directory" node of the repository. For projects without a .project file, you will want to use the [import as new project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Use_the_New_Projects_Wizard) option.

Comment: Works for me. But I can't seem to reference the project as a library project in other Android projects. Any step I am overlooking?